# How to see the throttled reads graph for a DynamoDb table in AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am reading the article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-scaling-for-amazon-dynamodb/ and this article mentions the throttled reads graph.  I cannot find this graph in AWS.  Please see the picture what I see, it is only capacity 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AWS Console, navigate to th DynamoDB dashboard.

Select the table you'd like to review.

Choose the Metrics tab.

Under "Capcity: table" you should be able to see "Throttled read requests".  Click on it for added detail/options.